# How to configure and use dictionary compression in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, dictionary

I want to know the flow of the dictionary compression in MongoDB 3.0 code with WiredTiger engine. But I haven't found the way to enable dictionary compression which is disabled by default. It seems there is a configuration item named 'dictionary' to specify the dictionary slot number. But where and how should I provide its value?

BTW: I would really appreciate it if some MongoDB code analysis resource can be provided.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.0, WiredTiger provides three compression options for collections:

- No compression
- **Snappy (enabled by default)** – very good compression, efficient use of resources
- zlib (similar to gzip) – excellent compression, but more resource intensive

  You can enable WiredTiger storage engine with one of the above compression options using:

  ```
  mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor snappy
  ```

  You can also use a configuration file instead of commandline parameters to start 'mongod' with compression options. Refer http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage-options

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got that I can configure dictionary in a new created file WiredTiger.conf.